# How can I deploy a release signed apk to attached device using gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a keystore file with two keys: one for debug build and another for release build type. So my gradle build script generates two apks on need. Now, to deploy the debug build apk android gradle plugin has installDebug task in it but how about deploying the release build apk? Andorid gradle plugin doesn't have any task like installRelease. How can I deploy the release build apk directly to the connected devices using gradle?

Answer (score 1):

The Android Gradle Plugin already includes the `installRelease` task but if you don't see it probably there is a signing configuration problem.

From the [documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide):

> Finally, the plugin creates install/uninstall tasks for all build
>   types (debug, release, test), as long as they can be installed (which
>   requires signing).

You can try to figure out what's wrong with the `signingReport` task:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've run signingReport and it shows all the build variants (e.g. debug, release, debugTest) How can I track whats wrong from this?

Comment: And btw are you really sure that android gradle plugin comes with default installRelease task? I've googled a bit but could found it anywhere. Could you please provide any link where I can get a look at it?

Comment: How do you use ./gradlew signingReport?